# Accesing getId from an ArrayList from within a HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, abstract-class

I have created a HashMap with the key as a class and the Value as an ArrayList of an Abstract Class and I wish to get the ID or the name from that Abstract class elements. 
However when accessing an element from the ABSTRACT CLASS it only returns what is in the abstract class and not the methods in the classes that extend the Abstract class.
Is there a way to gain entry on the methods that extends the abstract class without changing my abstract class to include these fields.

```
private HashMap<Persoana,ArrayList<Account>>Unu; 
    for (Entry<Persoana, ArrayList<Account>> entry : Unu.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().get(i).getClass().???) {
            System.out.println("found"+entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
            return entry.getValue();
        }
        i++;
        System.out.println(entry.getValue()); 
    }
    return null;
}
```

My asbtract class:

```
public abstract class Account  extends Observable{
    public abstract void retragere(int sumaDeRetras);
    public abstract void depunere(int sumaDeDepunere);

}
```

A class that extends my abstract class and a method that I wish to access in my main.

```
   public class SavingsAccount extends Account {
        private long suma;
        private Date dataRetragere ;
        private Date dataDepunere;
        private int interest=5;
        private int IBAN;
        private int idClient;
        private long watchedSum;
public int getIBAN() {
        return IBAN;
    }}
```

Comment: The solution can depends on what you need to do ? Why an `Account` doesn't have an IBAN in the first place ?

Comment: Because I use as guidance the type of the Account.(Savings or Spendings) and the IBAN is unique in one of these type not in both of them(For Example, I could have a Spending Account with IBAN 1212 and a Saving Account with the same IBAN and it  would be two different things)Or at least that is how I thought of doing it, I am not really sure myself on the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically can check to concrete class with `instanceof` and then cast the instance. So in your case that would look like:

```
private HashMap<Persoana,ArrayList<Account>>Unu; 

for (Entry<Persoana, ArrayList<Account>> entry : Unu.entrySet()) {
    for (Account account : entry.getValue() {
        if (account instanceof SavingsAccount) {
            SavingsAccount savingsAccount = (SavingsAccount) account;

            System.out.println("found "+savingsAccount.getIBAN());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try is.But, I am not looking for an instance of SavingsAccount. A person can have multiple Savings Accounts which have a different IBAN. I am searching for an account that has a specific IBAN (from  input).

Comment: But you could then just compare your input IBAN the IBAN of the savingsAccount or am I missing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can downcast and then call the method like:

```
Account accountValue = entry.getValue();
if(accountValue instanceOf SavingsAccount) {
    SavingsAccount savingAccountValue = (SavingsAccount)accountValue;
    System.out.println(savingAccountValue.getIBAN());
}
```

Comment: You cannot cast and then check instance of, it has no sense, you have to do it in the other way

Answer (score -1):

If you know the concrete class, use the cast in the above answers. If you know only the concrete method, you can use the reflection as below:

```
for (Entry<Persoana, ArrayList<Account>> entry : Unu.entrySet()) {
 for (Account a : entry.getValue()) {
  System.out.println(a.getClass().getSimpleName()); // Prints the name of the concrete class.
  try {
    System.out.println(a.getClass().getMethod("getIBAN").invoke(a));
  } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

If you want to list all methods of the class, you can use the reflection as well:

```
...
a.getClass().getMethods();
...
```

Comment: Hi all, could anyone tell me, why is the answer wrong?

Comment: It seems overkill to use reflection here to fix a design problem.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I wanted only add a 'generic way', how to get/invoke a method from an 'unknown' class.